# What is the best place to place a Comparator Class in Java

Tags: java, package, structure, comparator

I'm trying to decide where is the best place to put my comparator class on a Java project.

```
public class CustomerSortingComparator implements Comparator<Customer>{
 @Override
    public int compare(Customer customer1, Customer customer2) { 
     //... my implementation
     }
}
```

In my project I have several packages:

```
com.test.dao
com.test.model
com.test.controller
com.test.service
com.test.util
.....
```

I was thinking to add it to the util package since I can't find a good reference that suggests where to put it.

Comment: It depends. Besides you can always move it if you think you put it in the "wrong" place.

Comment: You could do com.test.comparator and put all the comparators in there

Comment: Does Student already have a natural order via the `Comparable` interface?

Comment: Hi @WJS, yes it has a natural Comparable implementation already. I edited the method because it was with using an incorrect object inside the implementation (Student) - The correct object was Customer. The example was just for illustration purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s clearly opinion-based, so I am hurrying to air mine. :-)

If your comparator is to be used *in one place only*, implement it where it is used. Inside the same class or *at least* in the same package. The design principle of high cohesion dictates that this is where it belongs. In particular because from Java 8 comparators can often be defined in one or very few lines of code, there is no point in putting it in its own class. Just declare it in the class or even inside the method using it:

```
    Comparator<Customer> customerSortingComparator = Comparator.comparing(Customer::getLastName)
            .thenComparing(Customer::getFirstName);
```

If on the other side the comparator is foreseen to be used in more than one class in more than one package, declare it in the package holding the `Customer` class. Again, the principle of high cohesion will tell you that this is the place.

**Real life story:** In the project I am working on they have put all the comparators that compare customers (for the sake of the example) into one class in a package separate from the `Customer` class and also separate from the classes using those comparators. It has given us a class with a non-existent cohesion and a lot of unnecessary coupling across packages. A very poor design.

**Link:** [Cohesion (computer science)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)) on Wikipedia

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this.